# Refresh a form skipping validation when press a button for close: jsf+richfaces

Tags: ajax, validation, jsf, richfaces, refresh

I am using JSF and richfaces. And I am new.

I am looking for information about reset a form in a popup after close it, I do not need to validate the form neither render it. I want to close it and then when I open it again I want the form to be clean.

I have looked information about this, however I do not find the answer to my case. What I have is :

```
<rich:popupPanel ....
     <a4j:outputPanel id="editPaneRegion">
          <h:form id="form2EditPane">
             <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="edit" ...>    
                <rich:validator>
                     <h:outputLabel for="nameContact" value="... " />
                     <h:panelGrid>
               <h:inputText id="nameVontact" value="xbean.selected.name" label="..." required="true" size="20" tabindex="1">        
               <f:validator validatorId="personNameValidator" />
            </h:inputText>
            <rich:message for="nameContact" ajaxRendered="true"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
               </rich:validator>

</h:panelGrid>

....
<a4j:commandButton id="update" value="..." action="#{xBean.edit}" render="form1EditPane:tableContacts, form1EditPane:contactSelect" execute="editPaneRegion" tabindex="6"/>
...
<a4j:commandButton id="close" value="..." oncomplete="#{rich:component('editPane')}.hide();return false;" execute="@this" ajaxSingle="true" immediate="true" tabindex="7"/>
```

The close button does not works as should be. If I oppen the popup, edit the inputtext and then I close the popup, when I oppen the popup again, it is edited the inputtext, however I want the original as it should be without the edition.

I have found the same question but anything solves my case : I have tried, using a4j:region, different combination of attributes for the button: inmediate= true, action={...clean}, ajaxSimple=true, .. however it doesn't work.

Have someone a solution for this case, I think I miss something obvious as this behaviour should be a common thing, though.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to rerender the form. Whatever you use to make the popup appear make it render the popup as well:

```
<a4j:commandLink … 
    render="popupPanel" oncomplete="#{rich:component('popupPanel')}.show();" />
```

And do not nest forms, you don't have to wrap inputboxes into a `<form>` like you do in HTML.

Comment: Thanks very much this works. However, I have to click twice in the boton for close it. I have discovered that if I take out <rich:validator> I just have to click once in the boton and as I have the f:validator, the validation continue working, do you have any explanation to this behaviour, which should be the most correct solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: The `<rich:validator>` is used the same as `<f:validator>`, you put it inside the component you want to validate, not around it.

Comment: I could close correctly by taking out the <rich:validator> and changed the button to:

Comment: I can close correctly by taking out the <rich:validator> and changed the button Moreover,there is still some case that fails. IF I try to render in <a4j:commandLink …   render="popupPanel" it works but when I want to save, I click onece the buttom and it does not happend anything, the second time I click it works. Why can be this behavior? why the first time I click does not happen anything? Could someone tell  me what can be related to?.